# Let T : $R^3 → R^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x, y, z) = (0, 2x, 2y)$

Tags: linear-transformations, nilpotence

> Let T : $R^3 → R^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x, y, z) =
> (0, 2x, 2y)$. Show that T is nilpotent of index 3. Find a vector v such
>   that $\{v, T v, T^2v \}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

I am struggling with this question
i looked over my notes and i google it to understand how to solve it
but no result

Comment: There are two questions here.  Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: i guess you are lacking the definitions: A matrix is nil potent of order $k\in\mathbb{N}$ iff $A^{k}\equiv 0$ and $A^{k-1}$ is not the zero matrix. So the first task would be to find the matrix $A$ for that linear map $T$.

Comment: @Max Though it's not hard to construct the matrix, it's simple in this case to simply write down the prescription of $T^3$ from the definition.  So constructing a matrix is an unnecessary step.

Comment: @Bye_World indeed, but the difficulty of a task depends on the performer. Anyway, if you want that basis, then the matrix makes the obvious vector $v$ even more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^3(x,y,z) = T^2(T(x,y,z)) = T^2(0,2x,2y) = T(T(0,2x,2y)) = T(0,0,4x) = (0,0,0) = 0\in\mathbb{R}^3$, for your first question.

Based on the above calculation, you just need to find $v=(x,y,z)$ such that $\{(x,y,z),(0,2x,2y),(0,0,4x)\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: may you pleas explain how is did you find (0,0,4x) ?
and is the basis

Comment: may you explain how did you get (0,0,4), and is the basis =(1,1,1)(0,2,2)(0,0,4)

Comment: because $T(0, 2x, 2y) = (0,0,4x)$ and yes that is a basis, but you need to prove that they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}.$